# Invalid method error when invoicing people in Magentos backend

Tags: php, magento, error-handling, magento-1.7

Whenever I try to invoice an order in the backend of Magento I get the following error:

```
Invalid method Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::roundPrice(Array
(
    [0] => 240
    [1] => including
)
)
```

And the trace:

```
#0 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice/Item.php(286): Varien_Object->__call('roundPrice', Array)
#1 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice/Item.php(286): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice->roundPrice(240, 'including')
#2 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice/Total/Subtotal.php(53): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice_Item->calcRowTotal()
#3 /var/www/magento/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php(501): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice_Total_Subtotal->collect(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice))
#4 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Order.php(139): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice->collectTotals()
#5 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/InvoiceController.php(86): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Order->prepareInvoice(Array)
#6 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/InvoiceController.php(177): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_InvoiceController->_initInvoice()
#7 /var/www/magento/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_InvoiceController->newAction()
#8 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('new')
#9 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#10 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#11 /var/www/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 /var/www/magento/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#13 {main}
```

And here is item.php if that is helpful: http://pastebin.com/HJHb7YEv

And here is the dev site: http://bit.ly/1mAxK2a

The site is running Magento 1.8.1 on AWS with a theme called metrostore from themeforest.

I'm not really sure what is causing this but I have noticed on product search pages of the site the price slider is showing prices further than the 2nd decimal point rather than rounding up or down to the nearest penny.

Anybody have a clue what's going wrong here?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: It seems you have overridden the Sales Module into local.
Please try to rename or disable it and check once again without overriding Sales module. If it works fine then you need to repair the Overridden module.

Comment: Praise jeebuz you were right! Thanks a lot for the help, this problem has been bothering me for over 2 weeks now and it was that simple! Thanks @Anx

Comment: By the way what is the meaning of Praise jeebuz ? :o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have overridden the Sales Module into local. Please try to rename or disable it and check once again without overriding Sales module. If it works fine then you need to repair the Overridden module.